# Programatically getting an effective POM using Maven Resolver Provider

Tags: java, maven, aether

## What do I want to do?

- Given a POM file on the local filesystem.
- I want to programmatically obtain the effective POM of that POM file. Specifically I want to do the following:

  - Resolve the POMs dependencies
  - Ensure that all parent POMs are processed
  - Obtain the list of dependencies of the fully resolved POM
  - And so on...
- I don't need to obtain transitive dependencies.

## What works?

I'm using [Maven Resolver Provider](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-resolver-provider/) which sort of works. However
I have to use a package private class `org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver`

Here a GitHub link to a sample Maven project that you can run: https://github.com/sahilm/maven-resolver-test

The example program does the following:

- Downloads the latest spring boot POM from Maven Central.
- Prints out it's direct dependencies (with parent deps included)

You can run the the program with:
`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.sahilm.maven_resolver_test.Test"`

## What I need help with?

- I need help with understanding why I have to use a package private class to get stuff to work.
- Is there another way to get the information I need?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, the above seems more like a series of statements.

Comment: Do you mean the `DefaultModelResolver` is package? Because `ModelResolver` interface is public?

Comment: @Ardesco I agree. I'm rewording the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use `ProjectModelResolver`. Here's a code snippet,

```
    DefaultRepositorySystem repositorySystem =
            new DefaultRepositorySystem();
    repositorySystem.initService(locator);

    ModelResolver modelResolver =
            new ProjectModelResolver(session, requestTrace,
                    repositorySystem, remoteRepositoryManager, repos,
                    ProjectBuildingRequest.RepositoryMerging.POM_DOMINANT,
                    null);
```

I've included a working code [here](https://github.com/indrabasak/stackoverflow-indra/blob/master/effective-pom/src/main/java/com/basaki/EffectivePomBuilder.java).

Comment: Awesome. This works. I skipped looking at this because I was unsure how to get a `ReactorModelPool`. Turns out I don't need to. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can create (in your project) a public class under the package: `org.apache.maven.repository.internal` that extends the package-accessibility class. Just use a class name that is not possible to be used in the furutre by the vendor.

```
package org.apache.maven.repository.internal;
public class VisibleDefaultModelResolver extends DefaultModelResolver{

    public VisibleDefaultModelResolver(RepositorySystemSession session, RequestTrace trace, String context, ArtifactResolver resolver, VersionRangeResolver versionRangeResolver, RemoteRepositoryManager remoteRepositoryManager, List<RemoteRepository> repositories) {
        super(session, trace, context, resolver, versionRangeResolver, remoteRepositoryManager, repositories);
    }

}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
ModelResolver modelResolver = new VisibleDefaultModelResolver(session, requestTrace, "context", artifactResolver, versionRangeResolver, remoteRepositoryManager, repos);
```

Comment: That's interesting. Never knew you could do that! I still have a nagging feeling that there's a public API that I'm missing and that I have to combine the maven resolver provider with something else. This is helpful though and I'll accept your answer if I'm not able to find a public API.